# How can I link two equations: $ap+bq+cr=dpqr$ and $Ap+Bq+cR=Dpqr$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given two equations, $ap+bq+cr=dpqr$ and $Ap+Bq+cR=Dpqr$, where $p, q, r$ are known and $a, b, c, d, A, B, C, D$ are unique and are functions of $p, q, r$ is it the case that $a=A, b=B, c=C, d=D$? I think it is obvious but this is the only thing in the way of an interesting theorem so I need to be absolutely sure.

Comment: What do you mean by 'functions of $p,q,r$?

Comment: It seems most unlikely, eg $3p+2q+14r=\frac{23}{3}pqr$ and $7p-13q+r=\frac{7}{12}pqr$ both have a solution $p=2,q=1,r=6$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant integers only, not rationals.

Comment: These equations are fixed. The point of the a, b, etc. being functions of the (known) p, q, r is that they are not just numbers. They are known functions so they have fixed values because the p, q, r are fixed. As such, they can have only one value, I think, and so the functions (a and A etc.) must be equal. If they were not equal, they would have two different values for the same function of p, q, r, which they should not have. I am not sure if I am explaining myself properly. Apologies.

Comment: I still don't begin to understand this. What about $p+4q-4r=pqr$ and $-7p+13q+13r=2pqr$ both with a solution $p=4,q=3,r=1$.

Comment: You might have helped me to answer my own question.

Comment: The equation ap+bq+cr=dpqr is fixed in that p, q, r are given and a, b, c ,d, being function of p, q, r are, similarly, defined. They cannot be any old numbers and the equation is the only one possible. If, for example, a(p, q, r)=7, b(p, q, r) = 9, c(p, q, r)=11 and d(p, q, r)=1, then the equation is 7p+9q+11r=pqr and there is no other equation of this form in p, q, r. Along comes Ap+Bq+Cr=Dpqr. It claims to be the only possible equation in p, q, r of this construction also for the same reasons: A, B, C, D are also functions of p, q, r but they are different ones. To be continued ...

Comment: My claim is that, since these equations are unique, it must be that A=7 also because a=7 and this coefficient of p cannot be anything else; similarly for B, C, D. In practice, I don't know that 7 is the right number but I do have a(p, q, r)=A(p, q, r) etc., which might lead to interesting results. I hope this helps.

Comment: In short, no it isn't! Sorry to have diverted anyone (to the extent that I  did).